# deviceready handler not being called ios phonegap 3.3.3

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

index.html

```
<script>
   function onDeviceReady() {
       alert("onDeviceReady");
       var options = {frequency: 500};
       watchId = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onFailure, options);
    }
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
</script>
```

Phonegap 3.3.3 device ready handler is not being called.

Comment: Looks good to me.  When you say Phonegap 3.3.3, do you mean Cordova 3.3.0 or are you using an edge version.  I assume you are trying this on the device/simulator and not through the web browser.  deviceready, will not fire in a browser.

Comment: oops, 3.3.3 was a typo, i was using Cordova 3.3.0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

remove app.initialize() from the script (that messes up the event handler)

Comment: what do you mean? there is no app.initialize in your code

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have included the phonegap.js (or cordova.js) script in your html. Otherwise your code is fine. Try commenting everything else except the alert in onDeviceReady() in case the issue still persists.

Try posting your index.html with the question if there are still issues.

Comment: Adding `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>` solved this for me. Thanks. I was under the impression that was injected automatically, obviously not.

Answer (score 2):

It is a best practice to set your event listener in a function after the document finishes loading. Try something like this:

```
<body onload="onLoad()">

function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
```

or with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});
```