# Phonegap: Device ready event not working when packaged with phonegap build and put on android device

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to make the example hello world phonegap application to work on my android tablet. I want the device ready function to fire and the it to say "device is ready" instead of constantly saying "connecting to device" Here is my code. I cant for the life of me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--
    Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
        https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
    Some notes:
        * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
        * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
        * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
            * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
    -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```js
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

``

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911155/deviceready-handler-not-being-called-ios-phonegap-3-3-3/20914593#20914593

Comment: I do not quite understand that answer